# https everywhere user rule doesn't work if there are bundled rules for the same site

Tags: firefox, https-everywhere

I tried creating a user rule for a website for which the extension has also bundled rules (which I did disable first), but my rule is not picked up by the extension.

The rule code, if that would help:

```xml
<ruleset name="Aliexpress">
        <target host="aliexpress.*" />
        <target host="*.aliexpress.*" />
        <target host="alibaba.*" />
        <target host="*.alibaba.*" />
        <target host="alicdn.*" />
        <target host="*.alicdn.*" />

        <rule from="^http:"
                to="https:" />
</ruleset>
```

Is it even possible to use user rule when there's a built-in rule(s) for the same website? What can I do if I want to use my own rule and not the built in rule?

BTW, I have also other user rules and they work flawlessly. So I'm indeed using the correct folder to store them, etc.

Comment: From the title, this sounds very much like a bug report you ought to direct at the developers of this addon.

Comment: Hmm good idea. I'll try to post it as a bug report too.